# Creating new socket after closing an old one causes connection refused

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm new to android programming and I'm trying to port a program from standard java to android. This java application contains sockets. When I ported the program I get a connection refused if I press a button too fast. I made a simple program for testing.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Socket mySocket = new Socket();
            InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("10.94.35.24", 5000);
            mySocket.connect(address, 5000);
            mySocket.shutdownOutput();
            mySocket.shutdownInput();
            mySocket.close();
            Log.w("Socket", "Socket closed");
            Socket mySocket2 = new Socket();
            mySocket2.connect(address, 5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
thread.start();
```

I have a server up and running on this IP and port and my program works fine on a java application on my computer. But on android the program gets the following exception when trying to connect to mySocket2

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.94.35.24 (port
>   5000) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection
>   refused)

My guess is that this has something to do with a limitation in the android OS but I hope not. Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong or can confirm that sockets have these limitations in Android?

Comment: You don't need to call those shutdown methods just before closing the socket. Closing is sufficient.

Comment: Tried that too, still works on my computer but not on my phone.

Comment: It wasn't intended as an answer. That's why I posted it as a comment.